# How to change AJAX code on a webpage that would remain after refreshing?

Tags: json, ajax, web-crawler

I wanted to crawl [metal-archives.com](http://metal-archives.com) and put the info in a database about metal bands. After looking at the code for a good 20 minutes I figured they keep the data in a JSON file that can be accessed with [this](http://www.metal-archives.com/search/ajax-band-search/) URL. The only problem is that the AJAX code is set to show only 200 entries per page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        createGrid(
        "#searchResults", 200,
```

At the top of the file I can see there are more than 11,000 bands, but only 200 showing. Also, when I click the different pages AJAX takes care of fetching the data dynamically, without changing the URL in the address bar, so I couldn't see the rest of the bands.

Then I tried changing the code above to `"#searchResults", 1000` hoping it would remain after refreshing, but, alas, no luck. Any idea how I could do that, essentially make it possible to parse the entire JSON to a Python dictionary and create a DB?

Comment: So look at what the ajax code is hitting and call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the url is always returning 200 records, you can call this url in loop until you get all the records

**Step 1**:

Using the below url, pass `iDisplayStart=0` and get first 200 records,

http://www.metal-archives.com/search/ajax-band-search/?iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=200

**Step 2**:

Parse the `json` and get the value of `iTotalRecords` in the json and call the url again and again in the loop until you get all the records.

You can change the `iDisplayStart` as `iDisplayStart+=200` to call next 200 records as below,

http://www.metal-archives.com/search/ajax-band-search/?iDisplayStart=200&iDisplayLength=200

and then,

http://www.metal-archives.com/search/ajax-band-search/?iDisplayStart=400&iDisplayLength=200

Hope it helps you.